# XSLT pass regex-group() value to variable and formatting it

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, saxon

I have not find clear example on how to do this.
I want to pass 2 regex-group result to variable inside analyse-string one should be tranformed from hexadecimal to decimal. for example take regex-group(2)=2 and regex-group(4)=30, regex-group(4) should be formated to 0.30 both value passed to variable lets say $rg2 $rg4 then calculating "($rg4*(100 div 60))+$rg2" "(0.30*(100 div 60))+2"=2.5 . If rg4=0.38 then final result would be 2.6333333333333333

```
    <xsl:analyze-string select="sbtime/@stmerid" regex="([hm]{{1}})([0-9]{{1,2}})([ew]{{1}})([0-9]{{0,2}})">
        <xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="regex-group(1) = 'm'">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="regex-group(3) = 'e'">
                            <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:text>+</xsl:text>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="regex-group(4) != ''">
                            <xsl:text>:</xsl:text>
                            <xsl:variable name="rg2" as="xs:float">{regex-group(2)}</xsl:variable>
                            <xsl:variable name="rg4" as="xs:float">fn:format-number({regex-group(4)},'#.##')</xsl:variable>
                            <xsl:value-of select="($rg4*(100 div 60))+$rg2"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:number value="regex-group(2)" format="1"/>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:number value="regex-group(2)" format="1"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="regex-group(3) = 'e'">
                            <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:text>+</xsl:text>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:if test="regex-group(1) = 'm'"><xsl:text>00:</xsl:text></xsl:if>
                    <xsl:number value="regex-group(2)" format="1"/>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="regex-group(4) != ''">
                            <xsl:text>:</xsl:text>
                            <xsl:number value="regex-group(4)" format="1"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
```

How to do this ? there is probably a clean and fast way.
I don't know if you have to use variable or if there problem of scope and cast values for this in xslt.

EDIT: I think I ask this question because I initially tried this:

```
<xsl:variable name="rg2" select="regex-group(2)"/>
<xsl:variable name="rg4" select="regex-group(4)"/>
<xsl:value-of select="((0.$rg4)*(100 div 60))+$rg2"/>
```

and it returned "not a valid instance of the x-path grammar" in xmlspy 
I am not sure on how to handle number and math to add the "0." in front of $rg4 like a string.

Comment: Try using the following syntax: `<xsl:variable name="rg2" select="regex-group(2)"/>`. -- P.S. Do not format a number you intend to use as a multiplier; a formatted number is a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax to bind the result of evaluation an XPath expression (like a function call which `regex-group(2)` is) is simply

```
<xsl:variable name="rg2" select="regex-group(2)"/>
```

`<xsl:variable name="rg2" as="xs:float">{regex-group(2)}</xsl:variable>` might do in XSLT 3.0 with `expand-text="yes"` set.

In general, if you have a string (like returned by `regex-group()`) and need a number of a certain type the call the constructor e.g.

```
<xsl:variable name="rg2" select="xs:decimal(regex-group(2))"/>
```

For your arithmetic computation `($rg4*(100 div 60))+$rg2` you need two numeric values while `format-number` would give you a string so I guess you rather want to define

```
<xsl:variable name="rg4" select="xs:decimal(regex-group(4)) div 100"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

I haven't managed to follow the full detail of what you are trying to do, but when you write

```
<xsl:value-of select="((0.$rg4)*(100 div 60))+$rg2"/>
```

then I think you are misunderstanding how variables work in XSLT. Variables are named values that can be used where an expression is expected, they aren't strings of characters that can be substituted anywhere in the text (that is, they aren't macros).

If $rg4 is the string "30" and you want the value 0.30, then rather than `0.$rg4`, you want `xs:decimal(concat("0.", $rg4))`